# cant seem to be able to get it to update with dropdown item selected?

Tags: javascript

cant seem to be able to get it to refresh with dropdown item selected?

just starting to try and learn this

schedule.csv

- Team,Hens,Chickens,The Bulls,Horses,Cows,Pigs,Ducks,Geeses,Cats,Sheep,Mice,Dogs
- Times,1900,2130
- Lanes,1 - 2,2 - 3,4 - 5,6 - 7,7 - 8,9 - 10
- 13th September 2016,1-2,3-4,5-6,7-8,9-10,11-12
- 20th September 2016,4-5 ,6-2,12-3,9-11,1-7,10-8
- 27th September 2016,9-3,1-10,11-4,5-12,8-2,6-7
- 04th October 2016,7-12,5-8,9-2,10-4,11-6,1-3
- 11th October 2016,11-8,9-7,1-5,6-3,10-12,2-4
- 18th October 2016,No Bowl
- 25th October 2016,10-6,11-1,3-8,12-2,7-4,9-5
- 1st November 2016,5-7,4-12,2-10,1-9,6-8,3-11
- 8th November 2016,12-9,10-5,7-11,4-6,2-3,8-1
- 15th November 2016,6-1,2-11,8-12,3-5,4-9,7-10
- 22nd November 2016,3-10,8-9,4-1,2-7,5-11,12-6
- 29th November 2016,8-4,7-3,6-9,11-10,12-1,5-2
- 6th December 2016,6-5,2-1,12-11,4-3,8-7,10-9
- 13th December 2016,Christmas Fun Night
- 20th December 2016,Christmas Break
- 27th December 2016,Christmas Break
- 3rd January 2017,3-12,5-4,8-10,2-6,11-9,7-1
- 10th January 2017,4-11,3-9,7-6,10-1,12-5,2-8
- 17th January 2017,2-9,12-7,3-1,8-5,4-10,6-11
- 24th January 2017,5-1,8-11,4-2,7-9,3-6,12-10
- 31st January 2017,8-3,6-10,5-9,1-11,12-2,4-7
- 7th February 2017,10-2,7-5,11-3,12-4,9-1,8-6
- 14th February 2017,11-7,9-12,1-8,5-10,6-4,3-2
- 21st February 2017,12-8,1-6,10-7,11-2,5-3,9-4
- 28th February 2017,Half Term
- 7th March 2017,1-4,10-3,6-12,9-8,7-2,11-5
- 14th March 2017,9-6,4-8,2-5,3-7,10-11,1-12
- 21st March 2017,11-12,5-6,9-10,1-2,3-4,7-8
- 28th March 2017,10-8,12-3,1-7,4-5,6-2,9-11
- 4th April 2017,6-7,11-4,8-2,9-3,1-10,5-12
- 11th April 2017,1-3,9-2,11-6,7-12,5-8,10-4
- 18th April 2017,2-4,1-5,10-12,11-8,9-7,6-3
- 25th April 2017,9-5,3-8,7-4,10-6,11-1,12-2
- 2nd May 2017,3-11,2-10,6-8,5-7,4-12,1-9
- 9th May 2017,8-1,7-11,2-3,12-9,10-5,4-6
- 16th May 2017,7-10,8-12,4-9,6-1,2-11,3-5
- 23rd May 2017,12-6,4-1,5-11,3-10,8-9,2-7
- 30th May 2017,5-2,6-9,12-1,8-4,7-3,11-10

code

var aval = 0;

```
  function show(aval) {
   sss()
  }

  function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
  }

  (function sss() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
    xhr.open("GET", "schedule.csv");
    xhr.send();

    function handleStateChange() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
        showData(xhr.responseText);
      }
    }

    function showData(data) {

      var rows = data.split(/\s+/);
      var rowNum;
      var cells;
      var cellNum;

      var team = 1 + aval*1;
      var contents = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nPRODID:-//HullTenpin//EN\nVERSION:2.0\nCALSCALE:GREGORIAN\nMETHOD:PUBLISH\nX-WR-CALNAME:Bowling\nX-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/London\nX-WR-CALDESC:\n"
      var table = document.createElement("table");
      var rowss = data.split("\n");
      for (var i = 3; i < rowss.length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cells = rowss[i].split(",");
        var teamss = rowss[0].split(",");
        var times = rowss[1].split(",");
        var lanes = rowss[2].split(",");
        var lanee = lanes[1].split(" - ");
        var lane = lanee[0]*1 -1
        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
          var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
          cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
          var teams = cells[j].split("-");


          var str1 = cells[0];

          str1 = str1.replace (/st/g, "");
          str1 = str1.replace (/nd/g, "");
          str1 = str1.replace (/rd/g, "");
          str1 = str1.replace (/th/g, "");   
          var locales = ["hu", "en-US"],
          length = locales.length,   
          dateFormat = null;
          var objDate = new Date(str1),
          dateFormat = objDate.toLocaleString(locales[0], {
            year: "numeric",
            month: "numeric",
            day: "numeric"
          });
          dateFormat = dateFormat.replace (/\./g, "");
          dateFormat = dateFormat.replace (/ /g, "");
          if (team == teams[0]){
            var lanea = j*1 + lane*1 + (j - 1)
            var laneb = j*1 + lane*1 + (j - 1)+ 1
            var contents = contents + "BEGIN:VEVENT\n"
            var contents = contents + "DTSTART:" + dateFormat + times[1] +"00Z\n";
            var contents = contents + "DTEND:" + dateFormat + times[2] +"00Z\n";
            var contents = contents + "LOCATION:Bowling Alley\n";
            var contents = contents + "SUMMARY:" + teamss[team] + " V " + teamss[teams[1]] + " - Lanes " +"("+ lanea + ")"+"-" + laneb + "\n";
            var contents = contents + "END:VEVENT\n"
          }
          if (team == teams[1]){
            var lanea = j*1 + lane*1 + (j - 1)
            var laneb = j*1 + lane*1 + (j - 1)+ 1
            var contents = contents + "BEGIN:VEVENT\n"
            var contents = contents + "DTSTART:" + dateFormat + times[1] +"00Z\n";
            var contents = contents + "DTEND:" + dateFormat + times[2] +"00Z\n";
            var contents = contents + "LOCATION:Bowling Alley\n";
            var contents = contents + "SUMMARY:" + teamss[teams[0]] + " V " + teamss[team] + " - Lanes " + lanea + "-" +"("+ laneb+")" + "\n";
            var contents = contents + "END:VEVENT\n"
          }

        }


      }
      var contents = contents + "END:VCALENDAR\n";
      document.getElementById('area').value=contents;



      for (var xx = 1; xx < teamss.length; xx++) {
        var select = document.getElementById("purpose");
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        var opt = teamss[xx];
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
      }
    }
  })();

</script>

<form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">
  <p><input type="text" name="name" value="schedule.ics"></p>

       <fieldset>
      <label>Pick a Team:</label>
            <select name="Teams" id="purpose" onchange="java_script_:show(this.selectedIndex)"></select>
       </fieldset>
  <p><textarea rows=20 cols=100 id="area" name="text" ></textarea> </p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Download"></p>
</form>
```

---

sorted removed (from function ss()

Comment: too much code not enough comments or questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: wanted to call function showData(data) after selecting team from dropdown box to update textarea with relevent team dates and lanes    tried calling sss() but does nothing?